# Bundle multiple IPA's within a single IPA

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipa

Is there any possible way to bundle multiple IPA's or individual iOS XCode projects so that the end result is a single iOS IPA, installable on an iPhone/iPad? I have a daemon app that is entirely separate from the main app that I would like to bundle if possible.

[Here is information](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/Componentizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001275-CJBDDCAB) on doing this for MacOSX apps. Does anyone know anything about iOS apps?

Edits in response to questions:

- It is a VOIP app, I guess not a true daemon
- It is not intended for distribution on the app store

Comment: Is this intended for the App Store?  Apple only allows apps to have a single executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have daemon apps on iPhone, only apps that allow certain things in multitasking (VOIP, location service, playing music, finishing data transfer)

Comment: Allow me to clarify, it is a VOIP daemon

Comment: Right, or in other words, "no".

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking DougW is right.

You cannot combine multiple application in one IPA. However, it's not because you can't put them in one IPA, but rather because iTunes and iOS will recognize only one application in such IPA.

IPA is just a zip archive with Payload directory which contains an app. You can manually create IPA with multiple apps in Payload directory, but iTunes will "see" only first (I believe alphabetically) in this IPA.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this for iphone. Applications have one single executable and run in sandbox without privilege to run daemon or other services.

maybe you can do this in jailbroken devices, but i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what Nick said, no you cannot combine IPAs.

To achieve background execution for VOIP, location, etc, you do not create and bundle daemons or multiple applications.  Instead you have to use the [techniques described here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), and are limited in what you can do.